# Resampling in R

Tags: r, loops, resampling

Consider the following data:

```
library(Benchmarking)
d <- data.frame(x1=c(200,200,3000), x2=c(200,200,1000), y=c(100,100,3))
```

So I have `3` observations.

Now I want to select `2` observations randomly out of `d` three times (without repetition - there is three combinations in total). For each of these three times I want to calculate the following:

```
e <- dea(d[c('x1', 'x2')], d$y)
weighted.mean(eff(e), d$y)
```

That is, I will get three numbers, which I want to calculate an average of. Can someone show how to do this with a loop function in **R**?

**Example:**

There is three combinations in total, so I can only get the same result in this case. If I do the calculation manually, I will get the three following result:

```
0.977  0.977  1
```

(The result could of course be in a another order).

And the mean of these two numbers is:

```
0.984
```

This is a simple example. In my case I have a lot of combinations, where I don't select all of the combinations (e.g. there could be say 1,000,000 combinations, where I only select 1,000 of them).

Answer (score 1):

I think it's better if you use `sample.int` and `replicate` instead of doing all the combinations, see my example:

```
nsample <- 2 # Number of selected observations
nboot <- 10  # Number of times you repeat the process

replicate(nboot, with(d[sample.int(nrow(d), nsample), ], 
                      weighted.mean(eff(dea(data.frame(x1, x2), y)), y)))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Juan. Just to be sure: This is **without** repetition, right? So I cannot select the same combination twice, right?

Comment: I can see that it is with repetition. How do I change it, so each selection is without repetition?

Comment: In `sample.int` you can use `replace = TRUE`, by default `replace = FALSE`. Ex: `sample.int(nrow(d), nsample, replace = TRUE)`

Comment: Thanks, Juan. But I still think that there is a problem. Consider the new example in the text. Here it should only be possible to get the result 0.984, but when I use your code I can get another result. Which indicating that it is still with repetition even when I use the code `replace = FALSE`.

Comment: I think it's correct, in the new example you can get 4 solutions. You can only get 2 numbers (0.976699 and 1), then you can get 3 (0.977) and 0 (1; mean = 0.976699), 2 and 1 (mean = 0.984466), 1 and 2 (mean = 0.992233) and 0 and 3 (mean = 1).

Answer (score 0):

I have check also the link you bring regarding this issue, so if I got it right, I mean, you want to extract two rows (observations) each time without replacement, you can use sample:

```
SelObs <- sample(1:nrow(d),2)
# for getting the selected observations just
dSel <- d[SelObs,]
```

And then do your calculations

If you want those already selected observation to not be selected in a nex random selection, it is similar, but you need an index

```
Obs <- 1:nrow(d)
SelObs <- sample(Obs, 2)
dSel <- d[SelObs, ]
# and now, for removing those already selected 
Obs <- Obs[-SelObs]
# and keep going with next random selections and the above code
```